# Show years not month in forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

The data am working with is shown below

```
254977 166862 192546 139148 158211 143186 129334 138307 175387 179093 179093 179093 173914 177048 159028 157566 173361 165577 156633 160009 169986 175534 182035 175418 190068 318906 206457 214399 227035 229593 304140 240359 219092 120673 229633 251370
```

used the code below for forecasting

```
#Conversion to a time series
Sales_products<- ts(myts, start = 2016 ,frequency = 12)

#Removing outliers
sales<- tsclean(Sales_products)

# Arima auto generated
arimafore = forecast(auto.arima(sales), h = 5)
summary(arimafore)
```

For summary() i got the results below

```
Forecast method: ARIMA(1,2,1)(0,0,1)[12]

Model Information:
Series: sales 
ARIMA(1,2,1)(0,0,1)[12] 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ma1    sma1
      -0.8670  -0.4627  0.5136
s.e.   0.1327   0.1962  0.3270

sigma^2 estimated as 328019666:  log likelihood=-383.05
AIC=774.11   AICc=775.49   BIC=780.21

Error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set 3485.018 16806.59 13183.17 1.960426 7.575784 0.3560643 0.1163094

Forecasts:
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Jan 2019       250494.1 227140.9 273847.3 214778.4 286209.7
Feb 2019       276820.3 248688.8 304951.8 233796.8 319843.8
Mar 2019       274574.5 229773.4 319375.7 206057.1 343091.9
Apr 2019       295608.1 241251.7 349964.5 212477.2 378739.1
May 2019       295778.5 223994.9 367562.1 185994.9 405562.1
```

Why is it the forecasting results that i am getting is in months, for 5 months jan 2019, Feb 2019 ,Mar 2019,Apr 2019 and May 2019 instead of having a forecast of 5 years, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023.

Comment: I have never used any of the functions you mention however when I look at `?ts` it states that the `frequency` parameter describes: `the number of observations per unit of time.` Thus by specifying `=12` here you tell it to look at months instead of years (for years you should specify `frequency = 1`) Obviously we have to know whether  `myts` is in months or years (again I never used this but it may help you)

Comment: The question is, what did you specify...? The way you initialize your ts object, you will have month. Just take a look at your Sales_products ts. h = 5 for forecast just means you forecast five steps ahead. If your time basis were month before - these will be month.

Comment: thank you, will take my h =5 as 5 months ahead. Thought was going to simplify h=5 to years. Monthly is okay also. I appreciate